# Analyze Stack Trace как его настроить

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Пытаюсь разобраться с ошибкой, мне посоветовали посмотреть.
IDEA Analyze -> Analyze Stack Trace.
Открываю его, а там пустое окно.
Что-то нужно включить в настройках?
Там можно подключить плагины, но насколько я понял это для расширенного просмотра.
Попробовал подключить  ProGuard plugin:
[image: Analyze Stack Trace]

так же ни чего не появилось нового. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Скопируй требуемый стек трейс. Выбери поочерёдно описанные тобой пункты. Скопированный тобой стек трейс автоматически помещается в поле ввода "Put a Stack trace..." ну а дальше дебажишь по стек трейсу.